# No .minecraft bin or resource folder!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I open my .minecraft folder and there are no bin or resource folders! How can I get them?

Comment: That happened to me too, I cannot hear any sounds in the servers. I thought this had something to do with there being no folders in the resource folder, but what do I do to fix the noise? I cannot hear anything in servers, but I can on a single world?

Comment: You might want to tell us what you're actual problem is. Not being able to find these folders isn't a problem unless you're trying to *do* something with them. What are you trying to do?

Comment: If you want a new bin folder you need to play minecraft 1.5 Only that version will generate it. 1.6 won't do that because it has a different launcher that does a different process

Comment: Voting to close as unclear and abandoned.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is obsolete; Minecraft no longer even has a /bin/ folder.

Answer (score 16):

The new minecraft launcher doesn't use a bin or resource folder. The bin folder is replaced by `versions\<version number>` and the sounds and music are stored in the assets folder.